# Does Go GC hand back memory to OS?

Tags: memory, go, garbage-collection

In many Java garbage collectors, free unused memory is never handed back to the operating system for other processes to use.

Does the Go language GC occasionally and release memory to the OS?

Comment: You are right. Closing this.

Comment: it's not the garbage collectors job to release memory to the system. There is a separate heap scavenger which notifies the OS when blocks of memory are no longer needed.